What are the direct summands of the right $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$
Let $p$ be a positive prime. Consider the right $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. What are the direct summands of $M_\mathbb{Z}$? In particular, I'm looking for those direct summands $X,Y$ such that $X \cap Y = 0$ and $X \cong Y$.
I appreciate any help.

Is there a typo in the very end? Or did you mean to write $X \cong Y=0$?

Excuse me. This is a typo. I fixed it.

Does $\mathbb{Z}_p$ mean the localization at $p$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p= \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$?

$\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Are you asking for $X,Y$ submodules of $M_\mathbb{Z}$ such that $M_\mathbb{Z} = X \oplus Y$ and $X\cong Y$? If yes, is it clear that such modules must exist?

Oh, I guess you just want to classify all direct summands. In that case it is helpful to remember that $\mathbb{Q}$ is indecomposable (same for $\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Excuse me. I think the question is clear. Isn't it?

Well, it is late in my time zone, so maybe it is.

Let $X$ be a direct summand of $M_\mathbb{Z}$ and $Z\subseteq M_\mathbb{Z}$ a submodule such that $X \oplus Z =M_\mathbb{Z}$ and $X\cap Z = \{(0,\overline{0},\overline{0})\}$.
First we are going to show that if there exists $(q,\overline{a},\overline{b})\in X$ with $q\neq 0$, then $Z\subseteq \{0\} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. Pick $(s,\overline{c}, \overline{d})\in Z$, then we have
$$ X \ni sp(q,\overline{a}, \overline{b})=(spq, \overline{0}, \overline{0}) = pq (s,\overline{c},\overline{d}) \in Z. $$
As $X\cap Z=\{(0, \overline{0}, \overline{0})\}$ we get
$$ spq = 0. $$
However, as $p,q \neq 0$ we must have $s=0$.
This implies that either $X=\mathbb{Q}\oplus M_1$ or $X=\{0\} \oplus M_1$ with $M_1$ being a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$.
Thus, we are left to classify direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. Every $M_1$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module which allows us to conclude that $M_1$ is in fact a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ vector space. Hence, every submodule $M_1$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a direct summand.
You are looking for direct summands of $M_\mathbb{Z}$ which are isomorphic with trivial intersection. The trivial intersection forces your summands to either be identical or to be of the form $\{0\} \oplus M_1$ with $M_1$ having dimension $0$ or $1$.
Thus, if you want to find two non-identical, isomorphic direct summands with trivial intersection, then they are of the form $\langle (0, v_1)\rangle_\mathbb{Z}$ and $\langle (0, v_2)\rangle_\mathbb{Z}$ with $ v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $v_1, v_2$ not colinear over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
